# How to change the file system name

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have the device name /dev/something and would like of change to /dev/anotherthing. How to do in linux system?
e.g.

# fdisk -l

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    52430847    26214400   1c  Hidden W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2   *    52430848   666957823   307263488    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       666959870  1465147391   399093761    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       666959872  1465147391   399093760   83  Linux
```

I want change of the device name from /dev/sda1 to /dev/anothername

You can help me?

Comment: It depends what it is.  Can you [edit] and provide more details.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: User661199, the device names are generated from the physical disks and partition layouts.  While it is possible to change the way this works, you almost certainly don't want to do this.  Tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve and why, there are probably alternative approaches.